# Is there a way to use my google instance in big query?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have set up a google instance SQL server. I have a company laptop and there seem to be some constraints in me connecting to the SQL server through google proxy as I keep getting x509 certificate errors.

Does Google have its own version of an SSMS e.g. BigQuery where I can use queries to create/alter tables as I would normally in SSMS?

I would like to perform something as simple as

```
CREATE TABLE [datam].[CashflowAgg_small] ( 
[JobID] INT,
[ReportingPeriod_ID] INT,
[EntityHierarchy_ID] INT
)
```

Is something like this possible or do i need to connect to an SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in management console for mySQL like there is one for BigQuery.
You can configure one of the following  [workbenches](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-tools#workbench).

The x509 errors with the SQL proxy are certificate signed by unknown authority errors and usually happens when the SSL configuration was reset and it generates a new CA certificate but your client key doesn't match. In Cloud SQL Console UI in Connections, you reset the SSL configuration and create a new [client certificate](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance#new-client)